# Make QWiget::createWindowContainer shows title bar?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In QT 5.9,I use QWiget::createWindowContainer embed external application.
But the embed application with no title bar and menu bar.

How to make title bar and menu bar appear?

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. As far as I understood [`QWidget::createWindowContainer()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer), it can embed a `QWindow`. I don't see how it can embed an "external application". Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: @Scheff, I'm guessing the OP means that the `QWindow` being embedded belongs to another process -- which is perfectly ok.

Comment: Does the external application's window have a title bar *before* you embed it?  The title bar (and window decorations in general) are usually managed by whichever window manager is active rather than the application itself.

Comment: @G.M. The `QWindow` of other process was the actual detail I would like to see exposed as sample code. ;-) The [sample in the Qt blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/) doesn't show such case though I can imagine it is possible. Actually, I just was about to fiddle with this until I realized that OP's question left much room for speculation. Btw. IMHO, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) couldn't hurt for any [tag:qt] question...

Comment: @Scheff, Understood.  And I certainly have no quarrel with you regarding the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :-)